# Kubernetes deployment to create a ReplicaSet with custom name

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

Is it possible to "ask" Kubernetes Deployment to create ReplicaSet with custom name?
E.g. I want it to be `nginx-replicaset1` instead of `nginx-8576854954`

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @Thomas I have windows containers and limitation is 15 symbols for hostname, so some are the same which makes monitoring crazy. Intention is to replace `8576854954` with `rs1` to make hostname name shorter

Comment: You can override the hostname, but then all instances would get the same hostname. Another option is to use a StatefulSet which would give you shorter and stable host names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to control the name of the ReplicaSets a Deployment creates.  Of note, each time you modify the Deployment, it will create a new ReplicaSet, and the Deployment controller will need to choose a new unique name, and it's very possible to have 3 or more ReplicaSets for a single Deployment.

In a comment you mention a "limitation of 15 symbols".  The normal suffixes added by a Deployment to create its ReplicaSets, and then by a ReplicaSet to create its Pods, usually add up to about a dozen characters on their own, so limiting names to 15 characters isn't reasonable for Kubernetes.  (There is a more general limit of 63 characters for a name, which comes from DNS's rules, but that's a much more manageable limit.)

Comment: 15 symbols is a limit for windows containers hostname, not k8s itself

Answer (score 0):

I know [karmada](https://github.com/karmada-io/karmada/tree/release-1.4) can set repilicaSet same name in multi kubernetes clusters, but i don't yet know what the technical rationale for its setup is。